# AllowGroups and root@IP

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, sshd

I've got several servers with the following sshd configuration.

```
# Authentication:
PermitRootLogin no
AllowGroups ssh
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

This means every user in group "ssh" can login but only with pubkey. The login of root is not allowed.

But there must be an exception for root: my backup server with $ip must login as root.

I tried:

```
AllowUsers root@$ip
AllowGroups ssh
```

But AllowUsers overwrites the AllowGroups statement. So only root from $ip can login in.

```
Match User root, Address $ip
    PermitRootLogin {yes|without-password}
    AllowUsers root
```

and

```
Match Address $ip
    PermitRootLogin {yes|without-password}
    AllowUsers *
```

Both are completely ignored. Still normal users in group "ssh" can login only.

It's a simply scenario with user login restricted to pubkey and root login restricted to pubkey and certain ip. How to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't posted your entire `sshd_config`, so it's a little hard to reproduce the situation, but this seems to work:

```
# Main config prohibits all logins
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers root

# Permit root logins from a specific address
Match Address 192.168.1.20
  PermitRootLogin yes

# Allow logins to anyone in "ssh" group.
Match Group ssh
  AllowUsers *
```

Another solution is:

- Have the following in your `sshd_config`:

  ```
  AllowGroups ssh
  PermitRootLogin without-password
  ```
- Make `root` a member of the `ssh` group.

  ```
  usermod -a -G ssh root
  ```
- Add a public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` with a restricted
  source address, like this:

  ```
  from=192.168.1.20 ssh-rsa ...
  ```

This will get you what you want:

- Only members of the `ssh` group can log in.
- `root` can only log in from the specific ip address in the
  `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: In authorized_keys the ip address have to be in quotes: from="192.168.1.20" ssh-rsa ... 
Both solutions work fine. I took the second way with authorized keys - maybe the more "standard way".
Thanks a lot!

Comment: AllowUsers in a Match seems to be prohibited and probably crashed ssh service on restart. (not sure though, long story...)